# How to declare attribute with EnumType

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In my itemtype I need to declare attribut with EnumType. But it is giving an error like below

```
  hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\antmacros.xml:795:
  java.lang.ClassCastException: de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YEnumType 
  cannot be cast to    de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YCollectionType
```

here is how I declare

```
<attribute qualifier="aaa" type="EnumType" autocreate="true" generate="true">
    <persistence qualifier="bbbl" type="property" />
    <modifiers  read="true" write="true" search="true" removable="true" 
     optional="true" />
     <description>aaa</description>
</attribute>
```

How to skip that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the EnumType actually created in enumtypes section? Try something like this:

```
<enumtypes>
    <enumtype code="MyEnumType" autocreate="true" generate="true" dynamic="false">
        <value code="SOMETHING"/>
    </enumtype>
</enumtypes>

<attribute qualifier="aaa" type="MyEnumType" autocreate="true" generate="true">
    <persistence  type="property" />
    <modifiers  read="true" write="true" search="true" removable="true" 
     optional="true" />
     <description>aaa</description>
</attribute>
```

This is the correct way to do it. First define the enum type and after that use it as a normal type.